# Guice TypeLiterals in Kotlin

Tags: generics, dependency-injection, kotlin, guice

I have a scenario where I have a generic interface and wish to bind multiple implementations of that interface in Guice. Normally in Java this would mean TypeLiterals, how would this be done in Kotlin?

```
bind(TypeLiteral<Resolver<RealObject>>(){}).to(RealResolver::class.java)
```

This gives a compiler error of: 
`cannot access <init>: it is public/*package*/ in 'TypeLiteral'`

There is a TypeLiteral.get() method however I cannot seem to get that to work either

Answer (score 11):

Instead of the Java anonymous class syntax (`new TypeLiteral<Resolver<RealObject>>(){}`), you should use the Kotlin [object expression](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#object-expressions):

```
bind(object : TypeLiteral<Resolver<RealObject>>() { }).to(RealResolver::class.java)
```

---

You can wrap that into an inline function with a reified type parameter:

```
inline fun <reified T> typeLiteral() = object : TypeLiteral<T>() { }
```

Then use it as:

```
bind(typeLiteral<Resolver<RealObject>>()).to(RealResolver::class.java)
```

Comment: I just want to add to this that it compiles as above - however remember to add @JvmSuppressWildcards on the injection points and the declaration

For example 
`bind(object : TypeLiteral<Resolver<@JvmSuppressWildcards RealObject>>() { }).to.....`

Then to implement
`class InjectionTest @Inject constructor(resolver: Resolver<@JvmSuppressWildcards RealObject>`